# Custom method inside Django admin does not throw its error - Why?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have an admin view in Django which should call and display the result of a custom method. I would expect the following: if that custom method raises an error, I'll see the error popping up in my Django admin view. However, the admin view displays a dash instead: *"my_custom_method: -"*. There is no error in the logs.

I do not want to wrap every of my custom methods in a try/catch block. Is there any other way I can force Django to display that exception and quit showing that admin page?

```
 class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields=['my_custom_method']

 def my_custom_method(_):
    raise AttributeError
```